# Flutter: Keeping a page in the background with which the user can interact, e.g. map while using the navigator to display new pages on top

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I would like to keep the map in the background while showing pages on top of it and leveraging the flutter navigator for that. I could not figure out a simple way to keep the map always available to interact with while navigating to new pages (if the new page leaves some space for the map to be visible).
Any tip on how to achieve that?
The only option I found is to use a stack and not use the navigator as the material route will basically make the previous page not available for interactions

Answer (score 0):

As you said, one of the possible solutions is to use a `Stack` widget.

A simple schema for solving your problem may be the following:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      //map page implementation
      //...
    ),
    Container(
      //overlapping content implementation
      //...
    ),
  ],
)
```

Pay attention to the stack's children order... one child will be shown on top of the previous.

I hope this will help you! ;)